# sharepoint how to add code handler for button click

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a SharePoint publishing page. I added a server button via SPD, assign the OnClick handler to btnSubscribe_Click. The question is, how and where can I add codes for this handler? If I have it inside a dll, how can I relate the SharePoint page to the .cs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add controls to publishing pages with SPD, I assume you mean you have added the button to the page layout? or master page?

To make an onclick work, as you know, you need to have a code behind, or script in code.

1) To make the code behind work, you need to make a custom page layout class, extend from `Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage`

Then change your page layout declaration to use your new page layout code:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

2) Or you can enable inline script through web.config, and have standard `<script runat=server>` sections

3) Or better yet, write a web part or a control that will do your subscribe action. And add that to your page layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I'll follow first method.

Comment: I think you can edit a publishing page in SPD if you detach it from its page layout. My preferences on the listed options in order would be: 3, 1, 2. And while I understand listing #2 for completeness purposes, I would probably never do it.